# Unable to set Finger Print Options in Ionic 4 - Fingerprint AIO

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, fingerprint, face-id

I am trying to using FingerPrint AIO native feature in Ionic 4. I have got it setup and running by following the guide (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fingerprint-aio) but without FingerPrintOptions.

If I keep the "show" object empty like this: show({}) it works fine but if I try to add option such as: clientId, clientSecret,... I get error.

I have below code:

### Code

```
this.faio.show({
    clientId: 'Fingerprint-Demo', 
    clientSecret: 'o7aoOMYUbyxaD23oFAnJ' 
    disableBackup:true,  
    localizedFallbackTitle: 'Use Pin', 
    localizedReason: 'Please authenticate'
})
.then((result: any) => console.log(result))
.catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
```

### Error

```
ERROR in src/app/pages/login/login.page.ts(211,7): error TS2322: Type '{ clientId: string; clientSecret: string; disableBackup: true; localizedFallbackTitle: string; localizedReason: string; }' is not assignable to type 'FingerprintOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'clientId' does not exist in type 'FingerprintOptions'.
```

### Currently, working using below code:

```
this.faio.show({})
.then((result: any) => console.log(result))
.catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
```

What am I doing wrong? Why I am unable to add FingerPrintOptions?

The code without fingerPrintOptions is working and tested on Iphone 8 (FingerPrint, Passcode) and Iphone X (Face ID).

Answer (score 3):

I checked in node modules those options are not available in FingerprintOptions
instead this is the structure

```js
this.faio.show({
     title: 'Biometric Authentication', // (Android Only) | optional | Default: "<APP_NAME> Biometric Sign On"
     subtitle: 'Coolest Plugin ever' // (Android Only) | optional | Default: null
     description: 'Please authenticate' // optional | Default: null
     fallbackButtonTitle: 'Use Backup', // optional | When disableBackup is false defaults to "Use Pin".
                                        // When disableBackup is true defaults to "Cancel"
     disableBackup:true,  // optional | default: false
 })
 .then((result: any) => console.log(result))
 .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
```